# Stop Files From Being Given the 'nodump' Flag When Accessed Over SMB

Tags: network, smb, file-sharing

Is there any way to stop files from being given the '`nodump`' flag when accessed over the network via SMB?  This happens all the time when I'm using files on the external boot drive I use with my iMac from my Windows 10 laptop, and it's started to annoy me.  I have to switch over to that iMac, either physically or via an SSH session, and run '`chflags dump`' on the affected files every time after this problem occurs.

Comment: @agarza:  

     My use of:  

 - Title case in my question titles, including this one
 - Leading indentation as opposed to inter-paragraph spacing for paragraphing in body text, including here
 - Additional quoting around code, including here

is _intentional_.  Please don't suggest editing my question to make style changes to the contrary any more.  Also, my only body paragraph here is on the _short_ side in length; it doesn't need to get split up into multiple ones.

Comment: Apologies. My edits are only in line with what is common practice on SE.

Comment: Your question needs more detail, i.e. what exactly must be done to reproduce the problem.  It is not clear to me whether you're seeing the nodump flag under Windows, or on the Mac after accessing the files under Windows, or ...

Comment: @KyleJones:  Sorry, I thought that was clear enough from context and/or wording.  I'm seeing the 'nodump' flag on OS X after editing the files from Windows.  I've made a small edit to note this in my OP; does that help?